# Catching Internal Sealed Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

Using the `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` / `AddPolicyHandler` retry pattern how can you perform a retry for an exception that you can't reference because of internal sealed?

Ideally I'd like to do this:

```
.AddPolicyHandler(HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError() //408, 5xx
            .Or<SocksException>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt))));
```

But unfortunately `SocksException` looks like this:

```
internal sealed class SocksException : IOException
{
    public SocksException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public SocksException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }
}
```

And thus cannot be referenced directly. Will catching `IOException` suffice?

Edit: I've tried by trying to catch `IOException`, which you would think would work...but it doesn't. Not sure what else I could try.

Comment: As the 'SocksException' is derived from 'IOException', you might try by catching 'IOException' like this -> .Or<IOException>()

Comment: Thank you, that's the best idea I could come up with - wasn't sure if there was something more I could do

Comment: When you say "you would think would work...but it doesn't", what do you mean?

Comment: well, it didn't appear to be catching the error and retrying - I've since realised it actually did, but on the final retry if it fails it will rethrow the caught exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that with Polly this is working but confusingly on the last retry if it *still* fails the exception is rethrown which lead me to believe that it wasn't catching it...

If you console log your retry you can see that it is.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

A bit fragile solution but with reflection you can do the following:

```
.Or<Exception>(ex => ex.GetType().Name == "SocksException")
```